# ubuntu USB device installation

Tags: usb-creator

I'm an almost complete novice in Ubuntu installation. I use some program since years, but never install it myself, and I would like to start to learn and be able to do so myself. I would like to install Ubuntu on a USB device first, but I don't know:

1. What version of Ubuntu to install?
2. Where to find and download this version
3. Where to find some explanations about how to prepare the USB device for that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to [the Ubuntu website](http://ubuntu.com) for all the answers.

The download page is [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Just press the button to download.

Scroll down on that page and you'll find instructions for [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) and [How to create a bootable USB stick on OS X](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx).

Or, with the ever-useful lmgtfy, you could just [Google it](http://bfy.tw/7Evp).